# White slide appears when using Angular-Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my first time using Bootstrap's carousel element in Angular and I am having an odd issue where a white slide shows up before each transition (see gif below). I followed all the basic steps on the ng-bootstrap Github page for setting up but I can't find the issue. Here are the relevant files:

Gif of the current problem:
https://ibb.co/p38LP4X

home.html

```
...
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [interval]="5000" [pauseOnHover]="pauseOnHover" [pauseOnFocus]="pauseOnFocus">
        <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>AS SOLID AS THEY COME</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <img [src]="img" alt="My image {{i + 1}} description">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
...
```

angular.json

```
...
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
...
```

I also have another bootstrap version included in index.html, as using only the one in angular.json does not make the carousel functional at all.

index.html

```
<head>
...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue, Deleting **ngcc_lock_file** file from location ../node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/**ngcc_lock_file** worked for me.